# Custom 404 page unique to a site collection

Tags: 2010, office-365, iis, 404

Is it possible to create a custom 404 page which is unique to a site collection?
Usually, the 404 page is common for all site collections in a web application. Is there any way around this?

One a side not: How does Office 365 handle this? Because it does not offer access to the web application level. How can you customise office 365 404 pages?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the value of the `SPSite.FileNotFoundUrl` property?

Comment: I am using 2010 :(